# Talend Context Variable with Date DataType

Tags: talend

I have been using Talend's Context variables for a while; however, I am now running into an issue as I have never used a variable with Date Datatype before. I have a field in the database called **my_date** and it is in the format of **"DD-MON-YY"** and I have created a context variable withe date datatype: **context.CLOSING_MONTH** and below is my query

```
select  id,due_date

 from my_table

 where trunc(due_date) <  '"+context.CLOSING_MONTH+"'
```

however, I have been getting the following error:

**java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected**

the value of context.CLOSING_MONTH is: 2019-07-01 00:00:00

the odd thing is that if I remove the context variable and put its exact value (hard coding it) the error disappears.

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
where  trunc(due_date)<TO_DATE('"+TalendDate.formatDate("dd-MMM-yy", context.CLOSING_MONTH)+"'
```

Date Format are not the same on the two sides of the comparison : `'DD-MON-YY'` and `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` . You'll have to even formats to make it work.

I am not totally sure about this, as the problem could be with `due_date` format containing characters.

In this case, you'll have to convert 'due_date' to a format which contains only numeric character :

```
 TO_DATE(to_char(due_date,'DD-MON-YY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'),'DD-MON-YY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English')
```

Let me know if this is working.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your suggestion. I tried both suggestions and the same error is being thrown.